# Make chef cookbook recipe only run once

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe

So I use the following recipe:

```
include_recipe "build-essential"

node_packages = value_for_platform(
  [ "debian", "ubuntu" ]                      => { "default" => [ "libssl-dev" ] },
  [ "amazon", "centos", "fedora", "centos" ]  => { "default" => [ "openssl-devel" ] },
  "default"   => [ "libssl-dev" ]
)

node_packages.each do |node_package|
  package node_package do
    action :install
  end
end

bash "install-node" do
  cwd Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]
  code <<-EOH
    tar -xzf node-v#{node["nodejs"]["version"]}.tar.gz
    (cd node-v#{node["nodejs"]["version"]} && ./configure --prefix=#{node["nodejs"]["dir"]} && make && make install)
  EOH
  action :nothing
  not_if "#{node["nodejs"]["dir"]}/bin/node --version 2>&1 | grep #{node["nodejs"]["version"]}"
end

remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/node-v#{node["nodejs"]["version"]}.tar.gz" do
  source node["nodejs"]["url"]
  checksum node["nodejs"]["checksum"]
  notifies :run, resources(:bash => "install-node"), :immediately
end
```

It successfully installed nodejs on my Vagrant VM but on restart it's getting executed again. How do I prevent this? I'm not that good in reading ruby code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make the `remote_file` resource idempotent (i.e. to not download a file already present again) you have to correctly specify the checksum of the file. You do this in your code using  the `node["nodejs"]["checksum"]` attribute. However, this only works, if the checksum is correctly specified as the SHA256 hash of the downloaded file, no other algorithm (esp. not MD5) is supported.

If the checksum is not correct, your recipe will still work. However, on the next run, Chef will notice that the checksum of the existing file is different from the one you specified and will download the file again, thus notify the `install node` ressource and do the whole compile stuff.

Comment: Thanks, The checksum was indeed MD5, it didn't bothered anymore when I used the SHA256.

Answer (score 2):

With chef, it's important that recipes be idempotent.  That means that they should be able to run over and over again without changing the outcome.  Chef expects to be able to run all the recipes on a node periodically, and that should be ok.

Do you have a way of knowing which resource within that recipe is causing you problems?  The remote_file one is the only one I'm suspicious of being non-idempotent, but I'm not sure offhand.

Looking at the Chef wiki, I find this:

> Deprecated Behavior In Chef 0.8.x and earlier, Remote File is also
>   used to fetch files from the files/ directory in a cookbook. This
>   behavior is now provided by #Cookbook File, and use of Remote File for
>   this purpose is deprecated (though still valid) in Chef 0.9.0 and
>   later.

Anyway, the way chef tends to work, it will look to see if whatever `"#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/node-v#{node["nodejs"]["version"]}.tar.gz"` resolves to exists, and if it does, it should skip that resource.  Is it possible that `install-node` deletes that file when it's finished installing?  If so, chef will re-fetch it every time.

Comment: based on the [log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5035245) it looks like it's rerunning the `remote_file` part.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience `remote_file` always runs when executing `chef-client`, even if the target file already exists. I'm not sure why (haven't dug into the Chef code to find the exact cause of the bug), though.

You can always write a `not_if` or `only_if` to control the execution of the `remote_file` resource, but usually it's harmless to just let it run every time.

The rest of your code looks like it's already idempotent, so there's no harm in running the client repeatedly.

There's an action you can specify for `remote_file` that will make it run conditionally:

```
remote_file 'target' do
  source 'wherever'
  action :create_if_missing
end
```

See [the docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_file.html).

Comment: It is not a bug to download the file each time unless an explicit condition to prevent that matched. It will ensure that the file is always the correct one, even if the remote one changes on the same URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a recipe only once overriding the run-list with *-o* modifier.

```
sudo chef-client -o "recipe[cookbook::recipe]"
```

> -o RunlistItem,RunlistItem...,   Replace current run list with specified items
>
> --override-runlist

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether your recipe is idempotent, you may be interested in ToASTER, a framework for systematic testing of Chef scripts.

http://cloud-toaster.github.io/

Chef recipes are executed with different configurations in isolated container environments (Docker VMs), and ToASTER reports various metrics such as system state changes, convergence properties, and idempotence issues.